# How to set abr(average bitrate) on mp3 files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, transcoding, bitrate

I need to convert my mp3 from constant or variable bitrate to average bitrate.   how can I do this?
I've used

```
-b 250k -minratre 50kb -maxrate 260kb
```

But it goes constant bitrate when I run the command.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-abr` libmp3lame option:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:a libmp3lame -abr 1 -b:a 128k output.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

`-q:a 0` will set bitrate to average `220-260kbps`

if you use `-b` (probably need to use `-b:a`) then it will be constant.

[See here: ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3)

Comment: Tnx but I don't want it be constant, there are three types average, constant, variable.I want the average type.